# SQLite trigger to SQL Server syntax

Tags: sqlite, syntax, triggers, ddl

i have a trigger in a SQLite table and i need to translated it to SQL Server
Hope you can help me, this is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table1
         AFTER INSERT
            ON my_table2
      FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table3
       SET answer = CASE new.question WHEN '1' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
     WHERE anotherQuestion = new.question;
END
```

I don't know how to translated it to SQL Server, thanks in advance

Comment: *"I don't know how to translated it to SQL Server"* - Reading the SQL Server documentation and trying it out would be a good start.

Comment: Woow! what a intelligent answer!, i tried already @Tomalak but thanks.

Comment: Great. If you have tried something, put it in your question. Show the code you tried and explain the problems you ran into. Cite error messages you got (except syntax errors) or describe unexpected behavior. This will turn your question from the current, rude *"write this for me"* into an actual question that has value for future readers.